# How to make in d3 force layout the gravity data dependant

Tags: d3.js, gravity, force-layout

I'd like to make a force layout with two types of nodes : type 1 stay in the center, and type 2 move in the periphery. There are links between type 1 and type 2, so the graph should stay together.

I imagine that i can do that with fixing the gravity positive for type 1 node and negative for type two :

```
  force.gravity(function(d){return (d.type=='pers')?10:-15})
```

but gravity seems to be a one for all parameter. Is there other way or can i change that to make the gravity parameter node dependent ? Or a completely different way to achieve this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The charge is an attribute of the force, not of the nodes. You can have different charges for each node. The nodes have negative charge, so they are attracted by the 'gravity' force and repelled by other nodes. If you set a greater (in magnitude) charge for nodes of type 1 and lesser charge for nodes of type 2, you may achieve the desired effect.

This talk by Mike Bostock explain and demonstrate different configurations of forces:

- [Talk](https://vimeo.com/29458354)
- [Slides](http://mbostock.github.io/d3/talk/20110921/#0)

Answer (score 3):

I tried this a while back and ended up with it not having any effect, also. If you look at the code, it appears that gravity is not capable of taking a function:

Compare .charge() and linkStrength():

```
force.linkStrength = function(x) {
  if (!arguments.length) return linkStrength;
  linkStrength = typeof x === "function" ? x : +x;
  return force;
};
force.charge = function(x) {
  if (!arguments.length) return charge;
  charge = typeof x === "function" ? x : +x;
  return force;
};
```

To .gravity():

```
force.gravity = function(x) {
  if (!arguments.length) return gravity;
  gravity = +x;
  return force;
};
```

I'm not sure if there are further constraints elsewhere, but if you pass gravity a function, it won't know how to deal with it.

Comment: I think the usual procedure here is to simply use `.gravity(0)` and then implement custom forces, e.g. the `gravity()` function in this example: http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1804919